# org-export to ignore strings within drawers

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I have the following set up for an annotated bibliography document.

```
** Kim, M. (2008): An inquiry into the development of the ethical theory of emotions in the "Analects" and the "Mencius"
:PROPERTIES:
:UNNUMBERED: t
:END:
:CITED:
[[Nivison, D. S. (1996). The ways of confucianism: investigations in Chinese philosophy. Chicago: Open Court.]]
:END:
```

The `CITED` drawer is used to keep track of important works that are cited or referenced within the book or article.

Exporting via LaTeX to pdf unexpectedly prints out items within the `CITED` drawer.

[image: unexpected behavior]

How do I suppress this unwanted behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to do it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30297651/6210219).

```org
#+OPTIONS: d:(not "CITED")
```

Comment: You can find the complete list of export settings in the [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html)